# Odata v4 - $expand then flattern result

Tags: odata, odata-v4

> **Objective:** To expand an object, and project a nested property, onto the root selection, alongside with other props.

Having the following relationship:

```
public class Product {
   public string Barcode { get; set; }
   public double Price { get; set; }
   public Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category {
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to make a projection which will result in this:

```
{
   "@odata.context": "http://localhost/odata/$metadata#Product",
   "value": [
      {
         "Price": 500,
         "Name": "Meat Products" // this is category name, ideally would be to rename it to CategoryName
      }
   ]
}
```

Where as currently I get this:

```
{
   "@odata.context": "http://localhost/odata/$metadata#Product",
   "value": [
      {
         "Price": 500,
         "Category": {
            "Name": "Meat Products"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

The query used is the following:

`/odata/Product?$expand=Category($select=Name)&$select=Price`

I would expect to write a projection like this:

`/odata/Product?$expand=Category&$select=Price,Category/Name as CategoryName`

or

`/odata/Product?$expand=Category&$select=Price,Category($select=Name as CategoryName)`

or

`/odata/Product?$expand=Category&$select=Price,Category($select=Name)`

#### Is that achievable ? Thank you!

P.S. OData V4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not achievable with odata v4 query semantic. As you can see, the response body contains a line:

```
"@odata.context": "http://localhost/odata/$metadata#Product"
```

This is to indicate the whole response payload represents an instance of 'Product' type. Suppose 'CategoryName' property does not exist on that type, it is not possible to instruct service to **dynamically** add one via the 'AS' clause. And keyword 'AS' also does not exist in standard OData query spec.

However, it is indeed valid to return an additional property beyond the metadata, see [Reference](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part1-protocol-complete.html#_Toc453752284).

> Clients MUST be prepared to receive additional properties in an entity
>   or complex type instance that are not advertised in metadata, even for
>   types not marked as open.

So in this case, the service could just return an additional 'virtual' property 'CategoryName' in the response. (If you're the service owner you can update response logic and do the change.) This could be a service behavior, rather than a reaction to certain client query.

Comment: Thank you. I see now the reasoning behind this limitation. Adding a virtual prop, probably won't be the best ideea in my case as the api is being used with different $expands by different consumers. Although it is a bit frustrating that there is no way to make a "Projection" with a final $select. It looks like its just a `.Select` and cast to anonymous object type, but I might be wrong.

Comment: You can do it by making your data entity an OpenType, then you can manually insert the child properties into the DynamicProperties bag on your now open entity.  But is there a good argument to do this? I'm not sure... once you are manually handing the output for a GET operation, you must now manually parse any POST or PATCH that the client returns, if you intend on supporting the client modifying the projection that you provided. I found it much easier to just update the clients to deal with the nested structure, you may not have this flexibility though.